# View Jmeter results in Bitbucket

Tags: jmeter, bitbucket

I would like to know what is the right way to view jmeter results in Bitbucket. Is it possible to also integrate results with slack?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.

If you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o report
```

The `report` folder will contain JMeter's [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and it will be possible to [export it as a build artifact](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/) so you and your colleagues would be able to download it and analyze.

Unfortunately currently displaying HTML reports directly in the pipeline page is not supported, you can express your interest in the feature [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-17678) of you want it to be implemented ever.

If you want to fail your pipeline if test results don't meet your expectations (i.e. response time is higher than expected or percentage of errors exceeds threshold) you can consider switching to an alternative way of launching a JMeter test like via [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) or via [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool with [Pass/Fail Criteria subsystem](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) enabled

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your reply. Yes, I definitely need to fail pipeline if the response exceeds certain number. Can you please let me know how can I install Taurus in Bitbucket and run it through pipeline? Thanks and appreciate your help!